# Mac application or method to arrange folders on archive DVDs with "best fit"

Tags: mac, archiving, dvd-burning

I'm archiving my home movies and have lots of folders (i.e. events) with between several hundred MB and a few GB of video files in each.  Is there an application or method to arrange these folders into groups to best fit the backup media?  (i.e. minimize the number of DVDs required)  I want to keep the contents of the individual folders together but mixing a small folder from 2009-02 and a larger one from 2011-06 to get a full DVD is just fine.

I'm using a Mac so an app would be nice but I'm fine with a command line solution.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is probably for you to simply place them in the burning folder according to the dates that you want together and then add a few more to reach maximum that you can tolerate being out of order.